# Pass model and modellist data together to a partial view - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. I need to create form in partial view. In this form I am passing `ViewModel` which hold all related model class instances. Now one of the model classes, I need to pass data list so that I can print in foreach loop in razor code.

Now what I need is to pass the model of few classes and list data of one model to view...

Many thanks

View model:

```
public class QualificationViewModel : LEO.DAL.ViewModels.IQualificationViewModel
{
    public Qualification _Qualification { get; set; }
    public QualificationType _QualificationType { get; set; }
    public Subject _Subject { get; set; }
    public ComponentScheme _ComponentScheme { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult CreateNewQualification()
  {
        var model = new QualificationViewModel();

        var ComponentList = //imagin this is list of components that i need to send along with viewModel             ??????????????????????

        return PartialView("PartialQualification_Create", model);
    }
```

View (need to fix this part (display list data here )

```
@model LEO.DAL.ViewModels.QualificationViewModel

 @*<div class="_FormGrid_block_1">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model._ComponentScheme.ComponentTitle)
                        </th>                         
                        <th>head1</th>
                    </tr>

                   @foreach (var item in Model._ComponentScheme)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem._ComponentScheme.ComponentTitle)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
            </div>*@
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If i understand corectly you want to send a list of objects type `QualificationViewModel` to the model ?

Comment: together with listdata of ComponentScheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to send the ViewModel to the partial view and in some cases send another list (ComponentList) to the same view? if that is what you want you have many ways:

Create a new view model that holds two properties: QualificationViewModel and a list of the type you want to send to the view and then bind your view to that new model

```
public class ExtendedQualificationViewModel
{

    public QualificationViewModel OldViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> ComponenetList {get;set;}
}
```

and in the view

```
@model LEO.DAL.ViewModels.ExtendedQualificationViewModel
```

Or you can do the same with extension of the original model like this:

```
public class ExtendedQualificationViewModel : QualificationViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SomeType> ComponenetList {get;set;}
}
```

and do the same binding in the view.

Lastly you can add the list into the ViewData and then retrieve it in the view.

Comment: yes i want to send list and models of few classes togather and your subscribe method works ... however i am getting error to display say example ComponentScheme.Title in loop in razor code

Comment: If you can explain the error easily here along with the way you implemented my suggestion I might be able to help, however it might be simpler to close this question (by accepting an answer) and post a new question with the new ViewModel, view and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Beside of knowing your question, the datamember `ComponentScheme` of 'QualificationViewModel` is not a list. So you can not iterate it using foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to loop list data in foreach loop with thanks to JTMon help

```
  @if (Model._ComponentScheme !=null)
                { 
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("abvc")
                        </th>                         
                        <th>head1</th>
                    </tr>

                  @foreach (var item in Model._ComponentScheme)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ComponentTitle)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
                }
```